# Show fragment with dynamic custom animation

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-animation

I am new to Android and having difficulty displaying a fragment with animation dynamically.

So far I animate fragment using XML files like below, which is working fine.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
transaction.add(R.id.task_fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Problem is in XML files, I have to hard coded `fromXDelta` and `toXDelta` values etc, but I want these values to be dynamic wherever user clicks on screen. I guess, I may not be able to do this using XML files. Is there any other way?

I tried experimenting with `AnimationSet` like this:

```
final AnimationSet animEnter = new AnimationSet( true );
Animation trans = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, 500, 0);
trans.setDuration( 140 );
animEnter.addAnimation( trans );
```

but I don't know how to use `AnimationSet` with `FragmentTransaction`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic animation you can set setCustomAnimations(0,0) for setting no animation by system and then from next fragment you can set transition object [setEnterTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setEnterTransition(android.transition.Transition))() in onCreate method of fragment.

Comment: thank you for answer. setEnterTransition() is available in API 21 or above, is it possible to use it in API 16? Also could you please provide example code for setting custom animations using this method?